# How do I aggregate more than one result into a SSRS list report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am creating a SSRS list report based on this SQL:

```
select name, job_id, job_title from HR


name        job_id      job_title   
---------   ---------   ---------   
Mike Jones  123         Manager      
Mike Jones  775         Analyst 
Patty Bea   562         Director
Patty Bea   964         Deputy CFO
```

After creating the design and previewing the report, I get 4 pages based on my SQL results.

[image: ssrs report preview]

When a name has more than one jod_id and job title, I would like to list both on one preview page of the SSRS report.

Answer (score 1):

Your preview looks like your desired result - 'I would like to list both on one preview page ' - rather than the 4 page current result.

If you haven't done it - you'll want to **only** GROUP on the name and use a **LOOKUPSET** to get all the values associated (and use a JOIN to combine them into a single string):

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!name.Value, Fields!name.Value, Fields!job_id.Value, "DataSet1"), ", ")
```

The **LookupSet** looks up all the results that match the `name` field (argument 1) to the `name` field of the dataset (argument 2) and gets the `job_id` field (argument 3) from **DataSet1** (argument 4).

For the `job_title` field, do the same but change the `job_id` field to `job_title`.